# How can I change the global variable in my function in python when it's not changing?

Tags: python, boolean, global-variables, binary-search

```
import random as rnd

notFound = False

def search(list, value):
    global notFound
    print(list)
    if notFound == False and len(list) > 3:
        middleElement = list[round(len(list) /2)]
        if middleElement == value:
            notFound = True
        elif int(value) > middleElement:
            search(list[round(len(list) /2):], value)
        elif int(value) < middleElement:
            search(list[:round(len(list) /2)], value)

a = rnd.randint(0,1)
list = []
while a < 100:
    list.append(a)
    a += 2

search(list, input("Input a value: "))

if(notFound == False):
    print("The value you passed isn't in the list!")
else:
    print("The value is in the list!")
```

I'm trying to change the global variable notFound in my search function, but it's not changing! I cannot seem to figure out the problem! :(

Comment: You're searching for a string in a list of ints, for one thing.

Comment: but I'm converting the string to int here: int(value)

Comment: Why are you using a global instead of simply returning `True` or `False`?

Comment: I thought about it before, but since I knew I had to recall the function many times over I did not think it would be suitable in this case, but now that I think about it, you're right, it's easier. Thanks!

Comment: Without looking at the code or addressing your particular issue, `if notFound == False` is a double negative implying that the the thing being sought was found. So printing out a message saying it isn't in the list is contrary to what the test implies. Your variable `notFound` should probably be renamed to `found`.

Comment: Yes, true. But the problem still exists! Now, I could change the function to: return True, but I want to figure out why the global variable isn't changing.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to cast your input to an integer

```
search(list, int(input("Input a value: ")))
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem, since I'm changing the input value to an integer in the function itself.

Comment: It should work because you forgot to cast value to an integer on line 10. My mistake though, I should've pointed it out directly even though this way is better practice.

Comment: See, the problem is that my global variable, which I've called "notFound" isn't changing to true, even if the code: if middleElement == value is true.

Comment: You've misdiagnosed the problem, the real problem is that `middleElement == value` is never true because value is a string while middleElement is an integer and python always returns false if you compare a string and integer. Add `print(type(MiddleElement))` and `print(type(value))` before the if statement to see what I mean.

Comment: It showed that they're both int. Try pasting my code into your editor. You will see that the if statement is working, just the global variable isn't changing.

Comment: Change `if notFound == False and len(list) >3` to `if notFound == False and len(list) >=3:` and `middleElement = list[round(len(list) /2)]` to `middleElement = list[round(len(list) /2)-1]`.This seems to work for most values other than the last and first number in the list